# Can I pick Jesus?

Tags: dharma, yoga, vedic-gods

I grew up in the west in a christian-dominated culture. I have listened to stories about Jesus since I was a child and have always respected his message of love and forgiveness. As I struggled to find a divine inspiration despite my lack of history with the Mahabharata and Ramayana it occurred to me that I could pick any higher power or elevated being or deva or sadhu. Why don't I just pick Jesus?

I am a believer of the Sanatana dharma. My thoughts and daily practice are those of a vedantist. I engage in daily meditation and strive to follow the disciplines of the sreya. Jesus would be more of a murti to me or object of my sadhana. I know this is not unprecedented as Sri Ramakrishna followed in Sanatana, Christian, and Muslim footsteps all 3.

Any thoughts? I dont want to offend anyone either way but I find that his message certainly has a place within my vedic beliefs. Any advice or path you could show me would be well appreciated. namaskar.

Comment: Where did you read that about  Sri Ramakrishna paramhansa?

Comment: I dont remember where I read that from Sri Ramakrishna. It's knowledge I've labored under for years. That was his big thing. He showed how the other deities were likely all god when we consider god in the 3rd form - formless.

Comment: He never followed. His disciples are making that up. BTW One can pick any object during sAdhana. The idea of sAdhana is to realize no-form from a form(or object). @Kauva

Comment: yeah exactly. I was beating myself trying to pick a deva being from the west and then I thought it could be any like sadhu or saint. the point is the actual devotion. So they really made that up? that makes me sad. I thought I might have some affinity for him and was planning to study his work. namaste. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Kauva I don't think this could be a reason to be sad. :) You can still read his works. He was hardcore devotee of Goddess KAli.

Comment: Since you're a vedantin, You may want to have a general discussion in this dedicated chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy

Comment: @KauvaAatma: Can you explain your 2 statements 1) **Jesus would be more of a murti to me or object of my sadhana**. (2) **Any advice or path you could show me would be well appreciated**.  Can you explain further as to what actually do you expect from the members of this site?

Comment: well, my beliefs are justified in my mind by science and not the mysticism that christians seem to thrive upon. I was just looking for viewpoints for and against selecting an avatar other than one from traditional Sanatana dharma.

Comment: There are certain lines which aren't very peaceful in the Bible do you support those lines as well? Like the lines about slavery?

Comment: @Wikash_I didnt say I picked their bible. I dont believe in that faith.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense then.

Comment: @Wikash_ tbf we have the dharmashastras

Comment: @Kauvasara the Vedic tradition is orthodox and there are many subschools some of which may be compatible and some which are not. Also, the Bible would likely limit you just as much as you have to pick one. Either respect Jesus, but don't see him as god and divine or stay Christian.

Answer (score 2):

And, why would that be offensive? Whatever Murti or saint that you choose is completely up to you. You have freedom in the Waking state . It doesn’t matter what you call your beliefs, vedantist, zen Buddhist, neutralist, atheists or anything. If you believe in something believe it with all your heart and use your own discretion to forge ahead in spirituality. Sanatana dharma is really not an organized religion. It is a set of well analyzed, well developed, well articulated works on spirituality for the well being of the Universe as a whole. It is more about understanding the personal You that resides in your Body. It is about realizing that and really experiencing it and seeing its splendor. It is about overcoming your own nature. It is about finding your roots as Sentient Human species and realizing that Sentience all around and those roots go high up to the stars. I should say not all of it is sweet . So you will falter and fall. In those failures to live up to yourself, in those moments of giving up, think about the deities that have sacrificed, think about the Sun that shines, think about the elements, think about the multitudes of elements and factors that made life possible. Just by thinking, just by reminiscing, you are thanking and that shall be accepted with grace and acknowledged. Names are time bound, Principles that run the Universe are timeless, Sanatana dharma is just today’s name, a set of pointers to those principles and evolved thoughts.